# Windows 10 command line to determine free space for non-windows drives

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot

Is there a way to determine free space for HFS+, ext4, etc drives in Windows 10, preferably through command line? I've googled, but everything I find is about mounting the drives which I don't necessarily want to do. If feels like this is possible, because my backup software (Acronis) seems to know the free space available on those drives. I need another method to provide the data.

Comment: I bet it can be looked up using diskpart, but I can't test HFS+ and ext4 because I only have NTFS available currently.

Comment: Do you mean for non-NTFS drives? Or just for any drive MS doesn't handle natively (ex, not FAT, NTFS, etc)?

Comment: Any drive MS doesn't handle natively, like the examples of HFS+ and ext4. I looked through diskpart and didn't see an obvious way... but I can definitely look again. Thanks.

Comment: Tried diskpart again. As far as I can tell, there is no way to get free space stats on partitions that are no also volumes (i.e., have a drive letter). I guess I'll see if I can mount the partitions as read only and get it done that way.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 does not come with drivers for foreign file systems like HFS+, ext4.

Try "Bash on Windows" eventually.

(Prerequisites - 64-bit version of Windows 10 Anniversary Update. Creators Update is recommended).

There are also third party drivers which give access to ext2/4(Ext2Fsd), HFS+(Paragon).

Before you access a drive/partition you usually mount it. There is also a way of reading raw disk sectors and interpreting them but every file system has its own layout, if you get what I mean.